# Hausdorff spaces for continuous bijections

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question being posed:

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection. Prove that if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $X$ is also Hausdorff.

Here's my attempt:

Consider any $a,b\in X$ with $a\neq b$. Then $f(a)\neq f(b)$ because $f$ is one-to-one. By the Hausdorff-ness of the image space, there is open $U$ and $V$ such that $f(a)\in U$, $f(b)\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

Then it is clear that $a\in f^{-1}[U]$ and $b\in f^{-1}[V]$, where the intersection is trivial, thus $X$ is Hausdorff as well.

The thing that concerns me is that I never used the fact that $f$ was onto. Did I use it without my knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surjective condition is not necessary. If we restrict the range of a continuous injection to its image, we end up with a continuous bijection with a Hausdorff space because subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are Hausdorff.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnC. No problem.